# Resolution of TIFF image created in C#

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, tiff, fax

For a fax management application, I have written C# code to create a TIFF file from scratch:

```
// Bitmap imgNew = new Bitmap(2550, 3300);
Bitmap imgNew = new Bitmap(1728, 1000);
imgNew.SetResolution((float)96, (float)96);

Graphics graphNew = Graphics.FromImage(imgNew);
graphNew.Clear(Color.White);

// Followed by a series of graphNew.DrawString statements

imgNew.Save(ms, ImageFormat.TIFF); // where ms is a MemoryStream
```

When uncommented, the first line will produce an 8.5" x 11" image with the text fields in the correct locations.  The second line has dimensions which are closer to those of files produced by an existing commercial application and the output file is about 1/10 the size of the file created by my app.  If I use a small value (46) for the SetResolution parameters, the text is very small but the document dimensions are correct.  Unfortunately, the file is still very large.

I am obviously not doing something quite right when generating my file.  The file details indicate that the horizontal and vertical resolution values are both 96, the bit depth is 1, and the compression is set to CCITT T.6.

What can I do to keep the correct format but reduce the file size?

Answer (score 1):

The fax size you want to use (1728, 1000) is probably 204 x 98 dpi. If you encode the resolution as 96x96 dpi, it will look squashed. That size bilevel image should compress to 20-100K bytes with T.6 (CCITT-G4) compression. If it's larger than 100K, either you're not compressing it as G4 or the image may contain lots of noise or gray/checkered areas. You can try a simple noise-removal function on the image to remove small "specs".